# I am unable to read or download a Image from Telegram message by telethon API in python

Tags: python, telethon

I am unable to read or download a Image from Telegram message by telethon API in python.

I get the image object from the function

async

```
def getPhotoImage(message):
    path = await message.download_media()
    return path
```

I call the function here

```
if not message.photo is None:
            path = getPhotoImage(message)
            print(path)
```

But unable to read the message , Please help in reading the image from the object

Comment: You should provide more information, but it seems you just forgot to `await getPhotoImage(...)`.

Comment: This is my Function

Comment: This is my Function
 
async def getPhotoImage(message):
    path = await message.download_media()
    return path

I am calling that in the script like this, where (message) is the message object, which has the Media

if not message.photo is None:
            path = getImage(message)
But , I the Image is not geeting downloaded anywhere.

When, Print Path , it returns an object like this, 

<coroutine object getPhotoImage at 0x0000020DB04CBD48>

Now, I need to get the image from the message and get the text either by opencv2 or pytesseract